# Gap fill in priority column + keep order

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

is there any good algorithm that will "fill" gaps in priority (or any other) column of table?
e.g.

## example

I have a table which structure looks like this:

```
id | text | subcategory | priority
```

and it is filled for example like this

```
1 | books    | NULL | 1
2 | dvds     | NULL | 2
5 | action   | 2    | 1
8 | romantic | 2    | 2
9 | fantasy  | 1    | 1
4 | sci-fi   | 1    | 2
6 | comics   | 1    | 3
```

In my design there is a option to change subcategory, if that happens priority is set to "new" priority and its value is highest in the subcategory it is currently in. 
**e.g**
change "action (id:5)" subcategory to "books (id:1)", its priority would be 4, that is ok, but now "romantic (id:8)" row has priority 2, and it is one and only in subcategory dvds (id:2).

```
1 | books    | NULL | 1
2 | dvds     | NULL | 2
8 | romantic | 2    | 2
9 | fantasy  | 1    | 1
4 | sci-fi   | 1    | 2
6 | comics   | 1    | 3
5 | action   | 1    | 4
```

-> I change fantasy (id:9) subcategory to dvds (id:2) and my priority is going to be 3.

```
1 | books    | NULL | 1
2 | dvds     | NULL | 2
8 | romantic | 2    | 2
9 | fantasy  | 2    | 3
4 | sci-fi   | 1    | 2
6 | comics   | 1    | 3
5 | action   | 1    | 4
```

It is alrgiht, but I need a function that will re-order everything by itself so I dont have to manualy change values of priority column. So priority column starts with 1.

Gaps start in row with id 8, 4.
Furthermore change comics category and then change it back, its going to be all messy there will be right order but it wont look as nice as I expect (for administration purposes).

Any ideas? **Pseudocode** or **logic** would be nice.

## edit - solution: pseudocode + logic

Since we know the count of rows in category and we can make a select that is going to be ordered by priority so we can just assign right number to each "new" priority.

e.g: 
ordered select returns priorities as follows: 1, 4, 5, 9, 10 
count(select) = 5 
so "new" priorities must be as follows : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Just assign in foreach loop new key to value.

since its in codeigniter:
$this->category_model->getPriorities("2") gets you all priorities in order (ASC) of one subcategory in my case 2.

```
public function prioritize(){
    $p = $this->category_model->getPriorities("2");
        for ($i = 1; $i < count($p)+1; $i++) { 
            echo "new[".$i."]->id[".$p[$i-1]->id."]->old_value[".$p[$i-1]->priority."]<br>";    
        }
}
```

output:

```
new[1]->id[9]->old_value[1]
new[2]->id[13]->old_value[3]
new[3]->id[14]->old_value[5]
new[4]->id[15]->old_value[8]
new[5]->id[11]->old_value[10]
```

Comment: I will try to help, but first I need to get the logic. What does priority do, and why when changing the priority of action ot 4, its subcategory is also changed? Or it's a reversed dependancy, where you are changing the subcategory (so books and dvds are categories?)

Comment: yep as you can see subcategory is every row that has NULL in subcategory column, priority is only for ordering on site menu.
If you change subcategory, priority is changed to new value: value = the highest value priority in new subcategory + 1. (this table I posted here is made up mine is bigger a bit, this table is explaining the purpose of question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE table as tb1, table as tb2 SET tb2.priority = tb2.priority - 1 WHERE tb2.priority > tb1.priority AND tb1.text = 'action' AND tb2.subcategory = tb1.subcategory;

This should solve the gap, every item with higher id, should drop it by 1

i.e. you have in this subcategory:

```
| priority |
|   1      |
|   2      |
|   3      |
|   4      |
```

if you move the item with priority=2

3 and 4 will move as 2 and 3

P.S.: This is the solution only for the gap, since the move issue is already solved in the other answer. It should be done before the movement, because the subcategory will change after it, and will not met the WHERE clause (the items from the old subcategory)

---

About the reordering the random gap:

Let's say we have priorities:

5, 10, 11, 12, 18, 20

which we want to make as:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

So the maximum number here is 20, which needs to be marked as 6

When it's done, the maximum number will be 18, which should be 5.

So everytime you use `UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE priority = MAX(priority)` it will get the maximum priority.

Here's my simple test:

```
<?php
for ($i = 6; $i>=1; $i--) {
    echo "UPDATE table SET priority = $i WHERE priority = MAX(priority) AND subcategory = X;" . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

which produces:

```
UPDATE table SET priority = 6 WHERE priority = MAX(priority) AND subcategory = X; // 20 becomes 6
UPDATE table SET priority = 5 WHERE priority = MAX(priority) AND subcategory = X; // 18 becomes 5
UPDATE table SET priority = 4 WHERE priority = MAX(priority) AND subcategory = X; // 12 becomes 4
UPDATE table SET priority = 3 WHERE priority = MAX(priority) AND subcategory = X; // 11 becomes 3
UPDATE table SET priority = 2 WHERE priority = MAX(priority) AND subcategory = X; // 10 becomes 2
UPDATE table SET priority = 1 WHERE priority = MAX(priority) AND subcategory = X; // 5 becomes 1
```

So you need to make a SELECT where you are selecting the subcategory, to put it instead of "X", then you need to count the rows for the while loop:

```
for ($i = $count_rows; $>=1; $i++) { ...
```

Ofcourse, you need to put the statement in the right query function, instead of echoing it, but it was for a test purpose.

Comment: very nice, this should be a solution for exact my problem, but lets "generalize", what if someone wants algorithm to **fill gaps and still have the same order**? I mean forget for a moment about changing categories and all that stuff. It is not necessary that gap will be only "1 number higher". Priority could be 5, 10, 11, 12, 18, 20 now I want it to change to 1,2,3,4,5,6 :) I know you do understand but I am looking for this answer.

Comment: It could take a time, to make it with pure SQL. However, I think about simple for loop in php, I will edit the answer

Comment: see my edit ;) did the same thing (in codeigniter).@Royal Bg: Ye its not about sql its combined with php...

Comment: nice :) glad to see it's all OK to you and hope the new users will use it as a note :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @NewPriority := MAX(priority)+1 FROM table WHERE category='$NewCategory';
UPDATE table SET category='$NewCategory', prioroty = @NewPriority WHERE id='$Id';
```

Comment: this is solved, I am trying to find solution for **filling the gap** that is created by changing subcategories too much. As you can see in my example, there is a gap in priority column, romantic category should have priority 1 instead 2. I mean I can change it manualy but I need a algorithm that will do this byitself.

Comment: This is what you need: http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/55481
Solution in the last reply

Comment: Sort of. Very nice sidenote thanks. Remember the priority column has its purpose (after any change it has to have its initial order)! The link you provided is not the solution for problem but it helps a lot.

Comment: But you can use it for any column

Comment: I know I understand it, I am looking for filling gap + keeping the order. That is the point of the question.